# How to clear the text within the text box?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

webdriver clear() is not clearing the existing text

I have tried `clear()` and it's not working, so tried `.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE))` but my senior doesn't want me to use the keys. So unsure how can i clear the text?

HTML of the element:

```
<input name="Quantity_110787" type="number" min="0" ng-model="invoiceLine.quantity" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-touched" ng-keypress="$ctrl.preventKey($event)" aria-invalid="false">
```

Code trials:

```
public void sendText(String text) {
        for (String control : controls) { 
        if(getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(control)).getAttribute("type").contains("number")) {
                getWebDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector(control)).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a", Keys.BACK_SPACE), text);
                break;
            }
        }
```

I want the text field to be cleared, so i can enter the new text. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

This should work as @Dark Knight said,

```
driver.findElement("locator").clear();
```

try to click before

```
 driver.findElement("locator").click();
 driver.findElement("locator").clear();
```

else try using sendKeys

```
driver.findElement("locator").click();
driver.findElement("locator").sendKeys("");
```

else try JS:

```
WebElement wb = driver.findElement("locator");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='';", wb);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this doing this way.

```
driver.findElement("locator").clear();
```

Comment: Already tried and it's not working so moved to Keys. My senior isn't happy with Keys.

Comment: Why to set the answer as negative, this is the basic way to clear. If that is not working for you it doesn't mean that is not good.

Comment: @KishoreJawalkar Contributors posting here are not here to make your senior's happy. This platform will just help you with solution/ approach.

Comment: @DarkKnight I know about this platform and don't want to get the answers which i know. So i clearly was looking for some answers other than i posted it.

Comment: @KishoreJawalkar Great. Please make sure going forward please make sure you do not include terms like "my senior's ..." in post. This doesn't add any value to your problem statement

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to invoke `clear()` method you need to induce *WebDriverwait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min.ng-touched[type='number'][name^='Quantity_']")));
  elem.click();
  elem.clear();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  WebElement elem = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@class='form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-touched' and @type='number'][starts-with(@name, 'Quantity_')]")));
  elem.click();
  elem.clear();
  ```